# Create multi-date google calendar event through URL

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build an URL which will direct the user to their Google Calendar and will show the create event page with predefined values. I've managed to build the URL that will create an event only for a particular day. My problem is how can i add multiple dates in the same URL?

My generated URL is as follow:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=New+Dynamic+Event&dates=20141204T073000Z/20141204T100000Z&details=Calendar+Details&location=My+Event+Location&followup=https://www.google.com/calendar&scc=1&sf=true&output=xml
```

This will create an event on 2014/12/04. How can i add more dates to this URL so that the event will be created on multiple days?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create multi date event in google calendar but you can insert the same event on different dates. Also, you can try using [recurring](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents) events. However these type of events has patterns like weekly,monthly..

Comment: How can i do that through a single URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you just provide the day date parts like

```
&dates=20170127/20170129
```

then this will raise the form with dates 2017-01-27 until 2017-01-28, and the 'all-day' box checked.

One day must be added to the date range.